# Espresso perform click on button located in fragment

Tags: android-fragments, android-espresso

I've got the following problem. I want to test my application with Espresso. Therefore I want to click a button which is part of the "Buttons" fragment, this fragment is located in a frame-layout in the MainActivity.

Ofcourse I can check if the frame-layout is displayed but I can not reach the layout of the fragment which is located into the frame-layout. 
So my question is, how can I reach the layout of the fragment into the frame-layout, so I can click on a button into the fragment.

The result at the moment is a NoViewMatchException:
android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with id:...

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** The exception shows the view hierarchy

These are the methods I'm calling:

onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.buttons)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));

This is the frame-layout in the MainActivity for the buttons fragment:

onView(withText("LOCATIONS")).perform(click());
The locations buttons is in the Buttons fragment

withId on the button id in stead of withText doesn't make sense.

Comment: Post your code and the full NoViewMatchException error

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Well I found a solution, but unfortunately I don't know the solution anymore

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear. It does not matter which layout you are using. Espresso can locate the element on the view hierarchy. If your case, you're getting NoViewMatchException. That means the view (R.id.buttons) is not there when you're checking.

For debugging, you can add some wait (SystemClock.sleep(2000)) and check if it works.
If that works, you need to write the idling resource to wait for the buttons fragment to appear.